# How to have a non-linear loss function in keras for heirachial models

Tags: python, regression, keras

I'm trying to build a simple one-output regression model in keras where I can have some measure of the confidence in my predicted value. To do this I would like to have a custom loss-function operating on two outputs which looks something like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred,y_error):
    return T.abs_(y_true-y_pred)*y_pred/y_error + T.exp(y_error)
```

however I can only have the two inputs y_true and y_pred, so is there a way to have a custom loss function of this form?

Alternatively, is there a better way to estimate confidence of my regression?

Answer (score 0):

In keras you can construct another Lambda layer that will calculate error and then you can include y_error into your y_pred (like `model.outputs = [last_layer.output,Lambda_layer.output]` ).